# Definition of a solution to a modulo

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have the following statement to prove, for homework:

If $r ∈ \mathbb{z}$ is a solution to $ax ≡ b ($ mod $m)$, then $r + mk, k ∈ Z$, are also solutions
to $ax ≡ b ($ mod $ m)$.

What does "$r ∈ \mathbb{z}$ is a solution..." mean? I assume it means $r=b$ since $b$ is usually where the modulo's solution is, but by symmetry the equation can be written as $b ≡ ax ($ mod $m)$, and now $ax$ would be the solution. Any insight on this problem is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: i expect that $a,b,m$ are given and that you are trying to solve for $x$.  Saying that an integer $r$ is a solution then means that $a\times r\equiv b\pmod m$.

Comment: Thank you! I’ll try to solve with that.